# How to create a dummy variable in Pandas Dataframe if a column matches certain values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas Dataframe with a column (`ip`) with certain values and another Pandas Series not in this DataFrame with a collection of these values. I want to create a column in the DataFrame that is 1 if a given line has its `ip`in my Pandas Series (`black_ip`).

```
import pandas as pd

dict = {'ip': {0: 103022, 1: 114221, 2: 47902, 3: 23550, 4: 84644}, 'os': {0: 23, 1: 19, 2: 17, 3: 13, 4: 19}}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict)

df
     ip  os
0  103022  23
1  114221  19
2   47902  17
3   23550  13
4   84644  19

blacklist = pd.Series([103022, 23550])

blacklist

0    103022
1     23550
```

My question is: how can I create a new column in `df` such that it shows 1 when the given `ip` in the blacklist and zero otherwise?

Sorry if this too dumb, I'm still new to programming. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What is obviously length of `blacklist` values?

Comment: It's MUCH smaller than the DataFrame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['new'] = df['ip'].isin(blacklist).astype(np.int8)
```

Also is possible convert column to `categorical`s:

```
df['new'] = pd.Categorical(df['ip'].isin(blacklist).astype(np.int8))

print (df)
       ip  os  new
0  103022  23    1
1  114221  19    0
2   47902  17    0
3   23550  13    1
4   84644  19    0
```

---

For interesting in large `DataFrame` converting to `Categorical` not save memory:

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)

df['new1'] = pd.Categorical(df['ip'].isin(blacklist).astype(np.int8))
df['new2'] = df['ip'].isin(blacklist).astype(np.int8)
df['new3'] = df['ip'].isin(blacklist)
print (df.memory_usage())
Index        80
ip       400000
os       400000
new1      50096
new2      50000
new3      50000
dtype: int64
```

**Timings**:

```
np.random.seed(4545)

N = 10000
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1000,size=N), columns=['ip'])
print (len(df))
10000

blacklist = pd.Series(np.random.randint(500,size=int(N/100)))
print (len(blacklist))
100

In [320]: %timeit df['ip'].isin(blacklist).astype(np.int8)
465 µs ± 21.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [321]: %timeit pd.Categorical(df['ip'].isin(blacklist).astype(np.int8))
915 µs ± 49.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [322]: %timeit pd.Categorical(df['ip'], categories = blacklist.unique()).notnull().astype(int)
1.59 ms ± 20.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [323]: %timeit df['new_column'] = [1 if x in blacklist.values else 0 for x in df.ip]
81.8 ms ± 2.72 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is there any diference if I use ```uint8``` instead of int?

Comment: @RaulGuarini - It is good solution if need save memory and large `DataFrame` :)

Comment: Yeah, this is really the case. The real dataframe has 200+ MM lines and a couple columns... only categorical data. Doing Machine Learning with it is a real mess in terms of memory consumption!

Answer (score 0):

**Slow, but simple and readable method**:

Another way to do this would be to use create your new column using a [list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i-use-it), set to assign a 1 if your `ip` value is in `blacklist` and a 0 otherwise:

```
df['new_column'] = [1 if x in blacklist.values else 0 for x in df.ip]

>>> df
       ip  os  new_column
0  103022  23           1
1  114221  19           0
2   47902  17           0
3   23550  13           1
4   84644  19           0
```

**EDIT: Faster method building on `Categorical`**: If you want to maximize speed, the following would be quite fast, though not quite as fast as the `.isin` non-categorical method. It builds on the use of [`pd.Categorical`](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/categorical.html#working-with-categories) as suggested by @jezrael, but leveraging it's capacity for assigning categories:

```
df['new_column'] = pd.Categorical(df['ip'], 
          categories = blacklist.unique()).notnull().astype(int)
```

**Timings:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(4545)
N = 10000
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1000,size=N), columns=['ip'])
blacklist = pd.Series(np.random.randint(500,size=int(N/100)))

%timeit df['ip'].isin(blacklist).astype(np.int8)
# 453 µs ± 8.81 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit pd.Categorical(df['ip'].isin(blacklist).astype(np.int8))
# 892 µs ± 17.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit pd.Categorical(df['ip'], categories = \
              blacklist.unique()).notnull().astype(int)
# 565 µs ± 32.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: How do you test it? It seems in small data or reapeting. And better here is not convert to categoricals, so what return `%timeit (df['ip'].isin(blacklist).astype(np.int8)` ?

Comment: Please check my timings, I was surprised with yours, so try create with large data.

Comment: Like I said in my answer, your `isin` method is the fastest :). I re-ran my timings on your larger datasets, I'll update my timings, one sec

Comment: on my machine, I still get a performance boost when I assign the categories when converting to `Categorical`, but it seems like we get different results with respects to that...

Comment: Ya, I am surprised too. I use pandas 0.22.0, python 3.5 under windows. And you?

Comment: so it is difference, hmmm.

Comment: Thanks a lot for showing another route! Actually, I was using something very similar to your first solution @sacul. But it was taking too long on my machine. Thanks once more!